# For loop to write file names

Tags: bash

I have a for loop to add the paths of some files to a text file.

I have 16 files, each of which is like `1a.mp4`, `1b.mp4`, `1c.mp4`, `2a.mp4`, `2c.mp4` etc.

I want to write the filenames that begins with each number to a text file. For example, all files whose name begins with `1` are written to `list_1.txt`. But I'm having one problem: With my code, as the name `10a.mp4` also begins with number 1, it's also added to `list_1.txt`, when it should have been in `list_10.txt`.

I need to make sure that only the files starting with the same number are recorded into the same text file, not just the same digit or character sequence.

Fortunately, files like `2a.mp4` and `3a.mp4` are classified correctly, since I don't have anything like `20a.mp4`.

Here's the code I have at present.

```
folder="videos"
NUM=1

for f in $folder/${NUM}*.${file_format}; do
  echo "file '$f'" >> "list_$NUM.txt"
done
```

Comment: why are you using `*`?

Comment: um, I'm having trouble understanding your statements, for example "*All from each number add path of files to txt file*", what does it mean? Also "*each files which start with 1 like 10,11,12 etc.. insert it also fits into a file with 1*" and "*only the files with the first file are inserted into the files of the first file*" and "*not all the files that start with the first one*".

Comment: @iBug I have many of video files, which insert path to text file. It's file like 1a.mp4,1b.mp4 but it is also 11a.mp4, 11b.mp4 and this one with start with 1 takes as 1, but I want it. :(

Comment: @Simonare Because of the sequence of the file alphabet and this file is join like 1.

Comment: Hold on. I'll make an edit suggestion so you can check if it better represents what you're trying to express.

Comment: What they're asking is simply a way to match filenames starting with 1 but not with 10 or any other numbers. Only match the filenames where the whole number matches the wanted number, and not those containing a larger number of which the first part happens to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
folder="videos"
NUM=1

for f in $folder/${NUM}[a-zA-Z]*.${file_format}; do echo "file '$f'" >> list_$NUM.txt; done
```

Comment: You don't really need the loop. `printf "file '%s'\n" "$folder/${NUM}"[a-zA-Z]*."${file_format}" >"list_$NUM.txt;"`... though the output is probably more useful if you remove the decorations.

Comment: Adjusted my answer with an even shorter (and prettier, and not using `printf` ) solution.

Comment: Hmm, did you forget the `echo`? Or do you really mean to run the `file` command on each?

Comment: You're right, I forgot the `echo`. I do think it's cleaner with a `for` loop then, although something with `sed` or `awk` would work too - or your `printf` of course.